# Service not removed after uninstall the application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have created the setup of window form application using visual studio setup project.
It install fine and works fine my application.

But when i uninstall the application it uninstall properly without any error, but the service of the application does not remove from **services**.

I don't know why this happens.

Please somebody help me. thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you do the uninstall?

Comment: This is extremely low on detail. you have to use tools or software libraries to install services and install an application, you mention non of these, or how you have set this up. please consider drastically editing your post to include all these relevant details

Comment: Hi BugFinder, i uninstall the application by click on uninstall icon of my application which is created at the time of installation.

Comment: Does the service go on reboot? If you've installed, stop the service, then uninstall does it go then?

Comment: Are you using VS Setup Project with Installer project add-on, or with InstallShield LE? Are you using installer classes to install/uninstall the service?

Comment: hi @PhilDW , i am using VS Setup Project with Installer project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a same issue in my application.

I just add the window restart code in installer class, so when i uninstall the application system restarts and application process & service both have removed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible reasons for this:

1. You did not add your installer class to every node of the custom actions list in your setup project. In other words, maybe there is no uninstall custom action so the service won't be uninstalled.
2. If there *is* an uninstall method, it will typically not stop your service unless you do that, by adding shutdown code to an override, before base.Uninstall(). That means it will attempt to uninstall it, probably mark it as Disabled in the services applet and remove it at the next reboot.
3. You might be using Installer classes (without using custom actions) and trying to run InstallUtil.exe. This is not the right way to do it, but if you didn't run it as uninstall custom action then you haven't uninstalled, and number 2 still applies. Finding InstallUtil.exe to do this is not safe anyway.

Having said that you still haven't been explicit about how you used installer classes, if they are custom actions, or if you're running InstallUtil.exe, if there is an uninstall custom action, and what is the exact state of the service after the uninstall.

Comment: Really appreciate these answers Phil - very useful to know - but wow, these installer projects really seem to cause more trouble than benefits? I suppose the pre-requisite functionality is allright?

Comment: Windows Installer has standard actions to install/start/stop services, which tools like WiX use - no need for installer classes. The prereqs are ok but VS supports only those in the standard list.

Comment: Are there any good reasons to use the installer projects that I am not aware of you think? I see almost only problems with the features I have looked at. Some OK GUI with simplicity to look at - I guess.